# Unsupported version 52.0

Tags: java, mysql

I know this has been asked before, I have read many of them. However, I can't figure out why it is not working. I have followed all the steps provided in similar questions like this one but I solve this error.

So my JAVA_HOME points to this:
jdk1.7.0_79.jdk

My compiler settings:
http://s32.postimg.org/vjyn87zs4/Screen_Shot_2016_05_01_at_1_54_42_PM.jpg

My installed JREs
http://s32.postimg.org/ykfy84s10/Screen_Shot_2016_05_01_at_1_53_39_PM.jpg

Everything I have tried to set it to 1.7, but still it does not work.

I don't know if this matters, but my dependency is:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Somewhere you have a class which was compiled in version 1.8.

Comment: How though? I have the JDK set to 1.7?

Comment: That won't change classes which have been compiled already.

Comment: How do I recompile everything then? would that be an efficient solution?

Comment: That is one option, however it is more likely you are depending on something compiled using Java 1.8

Comment: Is the mysql-connector-java compiled using Java 1.8? I only have two dependencies, that and JUnit

Comment: I suggest you check, you can look at the MANIFEST.MF , although I would be surprised if it was.

Comment: I think the issue is with your dependency according to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/6.0/en/connector-j-versions.html.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/6.0/en/connector-j-versions.html), you need jre 1.8.X to use the above dependancy.
Use a prior version and you should be fine.